# How can I make an Parallel AsyncTask or a method that reacts to a change in a variable in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I'm creating an app that shows bus location and routes in android with google maps. I have the bus location updates by running an AsyncTask getting a Json with the lat lon coordinates and modifying the value of the marker. What I want to do now is to modify the bus marker to display an ETA to the next bus stop (by measuring the difference of lat long to the next marker in route and assigning a time to it to count down to or another way). The thing is that **I don't know how to make a method that reacts to changes on the variable that is updated**

My questions are **Is it possible to make a method that reacts to the changes on a set variable? How can I achieve this?** or **Is there a way to run multiple AsyncTask to realize the updates I want to do to the bus marker?**

Note:I have a 15+ sized arraylist with the latlon of the bus stops markers. Since i believe i will have to do various methods to calculate and update the marker i don't know if asynctask would be good for it.

Note2: I keep calling the asynctask with a handler that executes every 10 sec like this:

```
 public void tiempo(){
    final Handler hadleupd=new Handler();
    hadleupd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GetBus().execute();//My AsyncTask
            hadleupd.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can basically do, is to add an Callback (or Listener) to your AsyncTask.

Inside your class, which is extending AsyncTask, you need to implement Listener interface.

Example:

```
public class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, YourDataType> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final Callback mCallback;


    public interface Callback {
        void onComplete(YourDataType result);
        void onError(Exception e);
    }

    public CustomTask(Context context, Callback callback) {
        mContext = context;
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(YourDataType result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (mException != null) {
            mCallback.onError(mException);
        } else {
            mCallback.onComplete(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Then, simply when calling the Task in your timer, your instantiating will look like this

```
public void tiempo(){
    final Handler hadleupd=new Handler();
    hadleupd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GetBus(getContext(), new Callback(
            @Override
            public void onComplete(YourDataType result){
            // Handle success
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
            // Handle Error

        }).execute();//My AsyncTask
            hadleupd.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not very well versed in android or java programming (barely have a month and a half learning/coding on them). If I'm catching the point of this, the AsyncTask GetBus will do is to do it's job and when it is done it will pass the result to what i add to the handle success success part? so i can call a method  and work each time the GetBus is triggered?

Comment: @IvanOgando Exactly :) the onComplete method will be called once the task is done.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go try this immediately!